# Can I write KDE rules for svn2git without using svneverever

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn, kde-plasma, svn2git

I want to start writing KDE rules for my SVN to Git migration. Can I simply see the SVN structure using 'repo-browser' (TortoiseSVN) and write the rules accordingly instead of installing `svneverever` to help determine the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. `svneverever` just helps you to investigate the history, especially if there was renamings and movings and stuff that is deleted now. If you don't want or need `svneverever` you can easily do without if you don't have a complex history with unclean working with SVN. But to run `svn2git` you need a local copy of the repo or need to run it on the SVN server anyway, so using `svneverever` on it is not too much extra effort.

Comment: How can I determine the structure?

Comment: By just looking at your history. That's also what `svneverever` does and then displays in a helpful way, especially for now deleted paths.